# Is "Geeky" or "Pop culture" the right word?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Let's say I'm creating a website where I will post trivia of video-games, famous book from the 21st century and popular tv-shows.

I need a domain name and I'm wondering if there's an English word I can use to describe my site. If I were to post a bunch of stuff about Pokemon, Twilight, Mass Effect, Breaking Bad, The Walking Dead, Harry Potter, can I use "geeky" or "pop culture" to describe that or are there better words?

Edit: I just thought of "Fiction", would "Fiction" suit my above examples too? Like "Fictiontrivia"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pop Culture" definitely describes your type of website. Pop culture is a broad term used to indicate any type of popular movie, game, book, etc. While geeky is more for specific things that are less popular and favored by a smaller stereotypical group, such as trading cards.

EDIT: I think fiction could possibly work, but it wouldn't appeal to your audience; it's more biased toward fictional novels.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Pop Culture Geek" since what you seem to imply is that you are into pop-culture? :)

Answer (score -2):

*meta*: For now, this is only a commentary.

---

Not *geeky*. Geeks are socially inept.

[pop culture](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pop-culture) fits, but.
*noun* modern popular culture transmitted via mass media and aimed particularly at younger people.

I think *pop culture* is '[too heavy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_culture)' a concept for the OP's context. Also, it has some [negative connotations](http://thesaurasize.com/pop+culture).

Comment: Comments don't have down voting, folks! Lol.